# How to install DL-Learner plugin in Protege 5.2 and newer versions?

Tags: java, machine-learning, plugins, owl, protege

I am trying to install DL-Learner in my version of Protege.

Maybe the main problem is that i cant find the right .jar file to add it on plugin directory.

Please, help me. I am trying for so long time.

Comment: did you ask the developers?

Comment: I found the right .jar file. Thank you! :)

Comment: https://github.com/SmartDataAnalytics/DL-Learner-Protege-Plugin/releases/download/v0.9-rc1/DL-Learner-Plugin.jar . If someone is looking for the same plugin